# Ancient babylonian geometry

Tags: math-history

An old Babylonian tablet calls for finding the area of an isosceles trapezoid whose sides are 30 units long and whose bases are 14 and 50.

Comment: What is your question? What is a "babylonian concept"?

Comment: By babylonian concept I mean we have our definitions and equations for the area of a triangle and rectangle, but was it different back then? I have to show work for the problem, I didn't want to show modern concepts in my work when I have to show how they did it.

Answer (score 1):

That Babylonian method is at least as easy to understand as the standard formula.

```
                          E___________  
                         /|          |\  
                        / |          | \  
                       /  |          |  \  
                      /   |          |   \  
                     /____|__________|____\  
                     A    B          C    D
```

The sketch above is not to scale, but it’s good enough to show the idea. You know that the distance $|AD|=50$, that $|BC|=14$, and that $|AB|=|CD|$, so you can calculate $|AB|$. You know that $\triangle ABE$ is a right triangle, and once you’ve calculated $|AB|$, you’ll know both $|AE|$ and $|AB|$ and will be able to use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate $|BE|$. With that information calculating the areas of the central rectangle and the two triangles is easy.

Comment: Thanks. But is finding the area of each individual piece by our standards today (equations for area) different than they did it?

Comment: @D-Man: They lacked our algebraic notation for writing those formulas, but they knew the Pythagorean theorem and a number of basic area and volume formulas, including those for triangles and rectangles.